# Why the view's margin has to be -20 to get it close to the end of the screen, why not zero?

Tags: ios, autolayout, margin, ios-autolayout

Screenshot:

[image: constraints are -20]

See, the leading, trailing and top is -20, but it's supposed to be 0.

Basically, I want the view to reach the end of left, right and top side.

In order to achieve this, it's supposed to be 0 but in practice, I have to give -20 to achieve that.

I think this has something to do with the top and bottom layout guides, but I don't know what it is.

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Are your constraints relative to margin?

Comment: I don't understand ... relative to margin meaning ? Can you please explain ? sorry

Comment: I am just setting the constraints parent view of viewcontroller thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up your constraints according to the **margin** of the actual superview, likely the main view of a view controller. To avoid doing that, hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> while dragging constraints, so that this menu...

[image: constraints with margins]

becomes this:

[image: constraints without margins]

If you already created your constraint, click on it and select the Size inspector (the fifth menu on the right). Check the properties of the first and second item and unselect **Relative to margin** in both.

[image: size inspector settings]

Comment: so why for margin - 20 ? why margin can't be there are zero ?